# I want to block some characters in html input tag so how can I do...?

Tags: html, input, character

**I want to block this characters:**

```
/ \ : * ? " < > |
```

Anyone here who can give me the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. [Do some research, search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=block+OR+restrict+special+characters+in+input+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan i am a new user

Comment: I know, so I gave you some guidance on how to ask question. Please look at the links I gave. they are all useful to you as a new user. Also look at the duplicates I posted for you they all can give you ideas